Webpack changes js class Names
I have a project written in React. I updated all the dependent modules in it and now, when building the bundle, I have a problem that the names of the js classes have been changed. If there was originally a class File, then after the build I get class <dir_name>_File. How can I disable or configure this? There was no such problem before updating all modules. To keep the names unchanged, I used the minimizer Options configuration.keep_class names = true;

The problem was in new webpack's configuration param called concatenateModules. If you disable this optimization you'll avoid the problem with changing js class names.
